# Ruby method call, element.send(), throws ArgumentError

Tags: ruby

When I run this Ruby code I get an ``` ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling ``method`` (0 for 1) ```.

```
def method(element)
  return element + 2
end

array = Array.[](1,2,3,4,5)

def map(array, method)
  result_array = []

  array.each do |element|
    # Call the method on the object
    value = element.send(method)
    # Add to array
    result_array.push(value)
  end

  return result_array
end

map(array, :method)
```

Calling the method this way works.

```
value = method(element)
```

What is wrong with the `element.send(method)` syntax?

Comment: Is this some learning task, to implement your own `map` method? If it is not then better to use built-in array methods https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html

Comment: You have a symbol `:method`, a method `method` and an argument `method`. Although that is fine technically, it makes your code much harder to understand.

Comment: "What is wrong with the `element.send(method)` syntax?" – Why do you think there is something wrong with the syntax? `ArgumentError` is a *runtime error*, so clearly the syntax is okay. If there was something wrong with the syntax, Ruby wouldn't even be able to parse it, let alone run it. The fact that the code runs, already proves that the code was parsed and thus that the syntax is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling the method this way works.
>
> ```
> value = method(element)
> ```
>
> What is wrong with the `element.send(method)` syntax?

In your example, `element` is an integer, and `method` is a symbol, e.g. `1` and `:method`.

So `value = method(element)` is equivalent to:

```
value = method(1)
```

whereas `value = element.send(method)` is equivalent to:

```
value = 1.send(:method)
```

which is basically:

```
value = 1.method
```

It should be obvious that `method(1)` and `1.method` is not the same.

Comment: I'm not a Ruby programmer but this question was posed by TripleByte (just the map method with the `result_array.push(value)` line missing {the question was to supply that missing line}. I added the `method`, `array` and call to `map`). They supplied the `value = element.send(method)` line. What you are saying seems to make sense, am I to take it their code was incorrect?  I've been testing in RubyFiddle.

Comment: @Joe you could get this working if you add `method` to `Integer`, i.e. `class Integer ; def method ; self + 2 ; end ; end`. However, the whole code looks quite contrived. Don't take that as an example of idiomatic Ruby :-)

Answer (score 4):

With `send` you need to pass a method argument `value = send(method, element)`. To call it on `element` is unnecessary. By the way, Ruby already has a method called `method` it is better to not override it. Rename it to something more meaningful like `add_two`.

Comment: Upvote based on this *" Ruby already has a method called method it is better to not override it. Rename it to something more meaningful like add_two"* because from the second I saw it in the OP my brain was screaming inside my skull

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky